# Installing kubernetes-dashboard with helm fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-dashboard

I've just created a new kubernetes cluster. The only thing I have done beyond set up the cluster is install Tiller using `helm init` and install kubernetes dashboard through `helm install stable/kubernetes-dashboard`.

The `helm install` command seems to be successful and `helm ls` outputs:

```
NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                           APP VERSION     NAMESPACE
exhaling-ladybug        1               Thu Oct 24 16:56:49 2019        DEPLOYED        kubernetes-dashboard-1.10.0     1.10.1          default
```

However after waiting a few minutes the deployment is still not ready.

Running `kubectl get pods` shows that the pod's status as `CrashLoopBackOff`.

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
exhaling-ladybug-kubernetes-dashboard   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   10         31m
```

The description for the pod shows the following events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From                 Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----                 -------
  Normal   Scheduled  31m                   default-scheduler    Successfully assigned default/exhaling-ladybug-kubernetes-dashboard to nodes-1
  Normal   Pulling    31m                   kubelet, nodes-1     Pulling image "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1"
  Normal   Pulled     31m                   kubelet, nodes-1     Successfully pulled image "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1"
  Normal   Started    30m (x4 over 31m)     kubelet, nodes-1     Started container kubernetes-dashboard
  Normal   Pulled     30m (x4 over 31m)     kubelet, nodes-1     Container image "k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    30m (x5 over 31m)     kubelet, nodes-1     Created container kubernetes-dashboard
  Warning  BackOff    107s (x141 over 31m)  kubelet, nodes-1     Back-off restarting failed container
```

And the logs show the following panic message

```
panic: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:exhaling-ladybug-kubernetes-dashboard" cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is it trying to create a secret somewhere it cannot?

Is it possible to setup without giving the dashboard account cluster-admin permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out mate:

https://akomljen.com/installing-kubernetes-dashboard-per-namespace/

You can create your own roles if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

By default i have puted namespace equals default, but if is other you need to replace for yours

```
kubectl create serviceaccount exhaling-ladybug-kubernetes-dashboard
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:exhaling-ladybug-kubernetes-dashboard
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the error you have posted what is happineening is:
 1. helm is trying is install dashboard but by default it was picking up the namespace you have provided.

For solving that:
 1. either you create roles based on the namespace you are trying to install, by default namespace should be: default
 2. just install the helm chart in the proper location which is required by helm chart, in your case you can do:

```
helm install stable/kubernetes-dashboard --name=kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating clusterrole

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:kubernetes-dashboard
```

Comment: Is it possible to resolve the issue without giving the dashboard account full cluster-admin permissions?